# Eigenfunctions of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory, eigenfunctions

I came across the following eigen-function problem
$$
\begin{align}
(a(x,t)\nabla + b(t)\Delta)f =& \lambda f\\
f(x)=&0 (\forall x \in \partial \Omega),\\
f(x)>&0 (\forall x \in \Omega),
\end{align}
$$
$\Omega$ is a convex, bounded, open domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d\geq 1$, with continuously differentiable boundary.  Here $a$ is an affine function in $x$ and continuously differentiable in $t$, and $b$ is a matrix.

Under what conditions does the minimal eigen-value exist?  When it exists, what is the corresponding eigenfunction?

I came across this problem in my readings and it is not directly my field, so I thought I should as here for some guidance.